# Composition and Infinitely differentiable in Normed vector space

Tags: normed-spaces, differential

Say, $U, V, W$ are normed vector spaces that has differentiation.
We know that if $f : U \rightarrow V$, $g : V \rightarrow W$ are differentiable, then so is $g \circ f$ and
$$D (g \circ f) (x) = Dg(f(x)) \circ Df(x)$$

Question is, if $f, g$ are infinitely differentiable, is $g \circ f$ infinitely differentiable as well?
Specifically, how do I go with induction step for $C^n$?

Comment: from this formula and induction, you can show that if $f$ and $g$ are $C^r$, then so is $g\circ f$.

Comment: I am lost on the induction step. How do I compute differential of $x \mapsto Dg(f(x)) \circ Df(x)$ ?